# Disable closing of sideNav when click outside the sideNav

Tags: materialize

I am using sideNav of MaterializeCSS in my application. I do not want to close sideNav while clicking outside. It can be achievable in modals like this:

```
{ dismissible: false }
```

How to do this in sideNav?

Answer (score 0):

MaterializeCSS doesn't have a built-in method for achieve this task, but you can use a workaround, unbinding the `click` event from sideNav overlay:

```
$(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

    $(".drag-target").unbind('click');
    $("#sidenav-overlay").unbind('click');
});
```

---

**Update:**
As of late, you can modify options of the sidenav by doing the following

```
$(".button-collapse").sideNav({
        menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
        edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
        closeOnClick: false, // clicking outside of the nav will not close it
        draggable: true, // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens,
        onOpen: function(el) {  }, // A function to be called when sideNav is opened
        onClose: function(el) {  }, // A function to be called when sideNav is closed
    });
});
```

you can take a look here to learn more: http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html

Comment: closeOnClick: false will not prevent the SideNav from being closed when clicking outside the SideNav. It will simply close the SideNav when you click WITHIN the SideNav area itself.